# How to export an entire Jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyterhub

I'm not sure if this place would be the appropriate place to post this question, but I wanted to download a folder with multiple Jupyter notebook so that I can view in my local server?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notebooks are all stored as `.ipynb` files in the directory where the notebook server is running. You should just be able to zip or tarball that folder up and then transfer them over to your local machine. Then just start a new instance of jupyter notebook in the location where you've put the files.